# Remove format option from file browser using ng-file-upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, angularjs-directive, ng-file-upload

I am facing a problem while I was trying to remove format selection option from file browser because if I am restricting use for selecting only CSV file user can easily change the format and select any file by just selecting `All Files` in format selection option.

[image]

I am using ng-file-upload for file upload  https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

I just need to know how can I remove this option.

Here is my code -

`<div ngf-drop ngf-select ng-model="abc.file" class="drop-box" ngf-drag-over-class="dragover" ngf-multiple="false" ngf-allow-dir="false" accept="text/*"  ngf-pattern="'text/*'">
                        Drop file here or click to upload.<br>Input file format: Text (.txt) file with one Id</span> per line.
 </div>`

By default it is giving me the option for selecting txt file but I can change the format to `All Files` and select all type of file. I have to remove the format from file browser or just give only option for selecting text/csv.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can't change anything about the OS-provided browser dialog.

Comment: You cannot control this. Web sites are sandboxed and can't control the OS options like this.

Comment: Actually, we can set default selection option that's the reason I was thinking if there is way to remove 'All Files' from that option list.